# MyBatis - How to unit test result maps?

Tags: unit-testing, mybatis

The mybatis documentation states:

> Always build ResultMaps incrementally. Unit tests really help out here. If you try to build a gigantic resultMap like the one above all at once, it's likely you'll get it wrong and it will be hard to work with. Start simple, and evolve it a step at a time. And unit test! The downside to using frameworks is that they are sometimes a bit of a black box (open source or not). Your best bet to ensure that you're achieving the behaviour that you intend, is to write unit tests. It also helps to have them when submitting bugs.

However at no point in the documentation do they explain how to unit test resultMaps. On their github wiki they have [a page on unit testing](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/Unit-Test) but it seems to be more geared towards contributors rather than users. How do I write unit tests for result maps as they recommend when it seems like I would need to build a fully functional in memory database just to test mappings?

Needing an in memory db sounds more like an integration test than a unit test and if any of my queries use db specific SQL statements like SQL Server T-SQL statements it couldn't properly test on an in memory db of a different type. Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct.

What is called `unit test` on the wiki is actually an integration test with the in-memory database. You can try to provide a mocked `DataSource` which returns mocked `Connection` and so on down to `ResultSet` but this is not very practical. Integration test is a better fit here.

I would say the main point is not about `unit-test` (which should have been called just tests in this context) but the incremental part. mybatis error messages in mappers are sometimes cryptic so using short (TDD like) feedback loop helps to deal with it. If you run tests for the single mapper you are working on edit-run cycle can be rather short.